# fetchmail /bin/sh: 0: Can't open date

Tags: email, command-line-interface, mta, fetchmail

I was running this from bash shell :

```
fetchmail -vk
```

it says in the log

> /bin/sh: 0: Can't open date

..and terminated.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question at all. If you didn't know, StackOverflow is for programming questions only. There are other sites in the StackExchange network like https://superuser.com

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.